# is there a tactic (other than inversion) that extracts implications from hypotheses?

Tags: coq

say I have the following goal:
[image]

To the human eye, it should be obvious that the only way H ends up being true is if n is either 7 or 21. I want to prove this using something like "Since H necessitates that n is either 7 or 21, the goal must be true."

My first guess was to use "inversion H" but that only adds another hypothesis of the same form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the shape of the hypothesis H, I'm afraid that the best strategy here is to brute-force: even if the match is printed in a concise shape, it computes as if it was composed of 22-nested pattern-matches like

```
H : match n with
    | 0 => false
    | S n1 => 
      match n1 with
      | 0 => false
      | S n2 => ... (* The case for 7 is somewhere there *)
     
        match n21 with
        | 0 => true
        | S _ => false
      end
     ...
   end
end
```

So you can repeatedly do a case-analysis on `n` discarding all the trivial situations where you obtain an hypothesis `true = false`.
Here is a way to do it:

```
Goal forall (n:nat), match n with | 7 | 21 => true | _ => false end = true -> n = 7 \/ n = 21.
Proof.
  intros n.
  repeat (destruct n as [|n] ; try discriminate). (* applies 22 times and then stops progressing *)
  all: auto. (* solves the last two goals by reflexivity *)
Qed.
```

If you don't appreciate the repeat clause, it is also possible to try to solve the problem with a dependent pattern-matching:

```
Proof.
  intros n.
  refine (match n as k return match k with | 7 | 21 => true | _ => false end = true -> k = 7 \/ k = 21 with
          | 7 => _
          | 21 => _
          | _ => _ end).
  (* 22 goals left *)
  all: try discriminate. (* solves the 20 absurd goals *)
  all: auto. (* solves the last two goals by reflexivity *)
Qed.
```

However, I couldn't advise to follow on this path: even if the proof script are "small", they actually expands to as many pattern-matches as the size of your largest integer (so the size of the proof is at least linear in the size of the largest constant you are matching as can clearly be seen in the second proof script).

A better way to solve this issue would be to modify the source definition that gave you this hypothesis H with `H : Nat.eqb n 7 || Nat.eqb n 21 = true` and use lemmas on equality (and maybe reflection, see the [mathcomp book](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/) for a reference on that topic).

Comment: that was extremely helpful. Thank you very much!